# Pulling Gmail "from:mailer-damon" and "from:postmaster" email data into google sheets?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I came across the code below in an article. I tried to modify it (`q: "from:mailer-daemon OR from:postmaster",`) so that the code can pull from not only `mailer-daemon`, but also `postmaster` emails. However, it handled the data differently for `postmaster` emails (`postmaster` recipient emails were put into the "Bounce Reason" column along with the reason). I'd also like for it to pull from a label I've created in Gmail called "Delete from CMMC List", but I'm unsure how to do that.

The column names that data is being separated into are as follows:

```
Bounce Date
Email Recipient
Error Status
Bounce Reason
Gmail Link
```

Original code that needs modification:

```
/*
* Gmail Bounce Report
* u/labnol Feb 12, 2020
* Written by Amit Agarwal
* email: amit@labnol.org
* twitter: u/labnol
* web: www.labnol.org
*/

const toast_ = e => SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(e);

const parseMessage_ = messageId => {
    const message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
    const body = message.getPlainBody();
    const [, failAction] = body.match(/^Action:\s*(.+)/m) || [];

    if (failAction === "failed") {
        const emailAddress = message.getHeader("X-Failed-Recipients");
        const [, errorStatus] = body.match(/^Status:\s*([.\d]+)/m) || [];
        const [, , bounceReason] =
            body.match(/^Diagnostic-Code:\s*(.+)\s*;\s*(.+)/m) || [];

        if (errorStatus && bounceReason) {
            return [
                message.getDate(),
                emailAddress,
                errorStatus,
                bounceReason.replace(/\s*(Please|Learn|See).+$/, ""),
                `=HYPERLINK("${message.getThread().getPermalink()}";"View")`
            ];
        }
    }
    return false;
};

const writeBouncedEmails_ = (data = []) => {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        toast_("Writing data to Google Sheet..");
        const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

        sheet
            .getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
            .clearContent();
        sheet.getRange(3, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        toast_("Bounce Report is ready!");
        showCredit_();
    }
};

const findBouncedEmails_ = () => {
    try {
        const rows = [];
        const { messages = [] } = Gmail.Users.Messages.list("me", {
            q: "from:mailer-daemon",
            maxResults: 200
        });

        if (messages.length === 0) {
            toast_("No bounced emails found in your mailbox!");
            return;
        }

        toast_("Working..");

        for (let m = 0; m < messages.length; m += 1) {
            const bounceData = parseMessage_(messages[m].id);

            if (bounceData) {
                rows.push(bounceData);
            }

            if (rows.length % 10 === 0) {
                toast_(`${rows.length} bounced emails found so far..`);
            }
        }
        writeBouncedEmails_(rows);
    } catch (error) {
        toast_(error.toString());
    }
};

const onOpen = e => {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .createMenu("‍♂️ Bounced Emails")
        .addItem("Run Report", "findBouncedEmails_")
        .addSeparator()
        .addItem("Credits", "showCredit_")
        .addToUi();
};

const showCredit_ = () => {
    const template = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("help");
    const html = template
        .setTitle("Bounce Report for Gmail")
        .setWidth(460)
        .setHeight(225);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(html);
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Can you share a copy of the Spreadsheet?